# Questions about what runs on the main thread during c#'s async await

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having trouble understanding what runs on the main thread during an async await operation and would be grateful for some answers.

Let's say I have a button that is supposed to log the user in.

it is supposed to block all other user input while the login process transpires, show a progress view and then when the result comes in display it

and here is the method that performs the log in

```
button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    do_login(); //I do not await the result
    do_some_other_stuff(); //this doesn't actually exist I just put it here to ask my questions
}

async Task do_login() {
    string user_name = txtUser.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    show_progress(true); //this is not an async method;
    string error = await _login.do_login(user_name, password);//this is an async method that can take up to 20 seconds to complete;
    show_progress(false);
    if (error != null) {
        show_error(error);
    } else {
        show_next_screen();
    }
}
```

I have two questions on the above example

a) What will be run on the main thread?

If I understand it correctly only _login.do_login will be run on a seperate thread, all others will be on the main thread, is this correct?

b) In what order will the methods be executed?

Again if I understand it correctly, it will be :

- do_login()
- show_progress(true);
- _login.do_login starts;
- do_some_other_stuff();
- _login.do_login finishes;
- show_progress(false);
  and it will continue from there

is this correct? if not, how can I achieve such a behaviour?

c) If my code above is correct then why do I keep receiving a warning that do_login() is not awaited? I do not wish to await it I just want it to run what it can and return when it wants, should I ignore that warning?

Comment: await doesn't make anything run asynchronously. It awaits an already executing asynchronous operation to complete without blocking the original thread. If `_login.do_login` doesn't spawn a new thread or doesn't use an asynchronous operation like `HttpClient.GetAsync`, everything may run on the UI thread. What does `_login.do_login` actually do?

Comment: BTW the *correct* way to implement an asynchronous operation inside an event handler is to change the handler's signature to `async void` and actually `await` the async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your main question is: *it depends*. The `_login.do_login` method will *likely* be put onto its own thread, but it actually depends on the .NET task scheduler. In WPF and ASP.NET it will be scheduled onto the thread pool if it doesn't immediately return a completed task.

The important part is that you know it will not block execution of the calling (in your case, the main) thread. Your understanding of the method flow is correct since you don't await `do_login`.

As far as the warning goes; you can mark `do_login` as `async void` to avoid it, though generally you only do that for event handlers which can then await a `Task` returning method. If you do go the `async void` route; make sure to put a `try/catch` in as such methods will throw all the way up to the root handler and can cause your app to crash.

Comment: It is dependent on task scheduler, but wpf and asp.net schedulers will schedule it on thread pool if it doesn't return completedtask before starting. Might be worth mentioning, because custom task schedulers are not seen that often.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, depending on the implementation of `do_login`, everything could run in the main thread. In this case I assume you're contacting a web server, so that part won't, but this is not always true. And asynchronous operation does not necessarily executes in another thread. One operation is asynchronous when:

- It doesn't block the calling thread.

Usually, UI threads run an 'event loop'. So an asynchronous task could simply put a new piece of work into the event queue to be executed whenever the scheduler determines, but in the same thread. In this case you don't use two threads, but still, you don't have to wait for the task to complete and you don't know when it'll finish.

To be precise, all the code in your post will run in the main thread. Only the part in `do_login` that manages the connection with the server, waiting and retrieving data will execute asynchronously.

You're mostly right about the sequence, with a few adjustments:

1. do_login() (until the await)
2. login._do_login() starts executing
3. do_some_other_stuff()
4. ...
5. login.do_login finishes
6. show_progress()

Comment: "The caller does not know when the task will finish (or if it at all)." I wouldn't say that.  Rather, that information isn't provided by when the method returns.   Most asynchronous operations provide some way for the caller to know when the method finishes, i.e. a callback, firing an event, or in this case, a `Task` that allows the caller to perform operations when the method finishes.   So all of that information is *there*, it's just done differently than for synchronous methods.

Comment: I meant that you can't determine when it will finish, but I think you're right, it might seem confusing. I'll remove it.

Comment: You don't know how long it will take to run before you call it.  That's true of a synchronous method too.  But you can "know" when it has already finished.  For a synchronous method you know because it returns, for a `Task` returning method you know because the task was marked as completed and ran its continuations.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about a 'point in code' more than a point in time. I mean. In synchronous code, if you have `f(); t()` you don't know **how long** it'll take for f to complete, but you know it's always before `t` executes. In asynchronous code this is not true, even if there are ways to execute code when it finishes. In the end, I meant that the order execution of asynchronous code is not deterministic

Comment: So the order of execution of asynchronous code may or may not be deterministic (depending on the particular operations involved), it's just *different* than for synchronous code.  The *way* that you go about running one operation after another is different, but you still can, which is a key point.